# Method 'GET' is not supported. org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```java
@RestController
public class userController {
    
    @Autowired
    userRepo Userrepo;
    
    @PostMapping("/user1")
    public userModel createUser(@RequestBody userModel user)
    {
        user.setUserId(111);
        user.setUserName("sury");
        user.setUserEmail("sury@gmail.com");
        user.setUserPass("LeoLeo");
    
        return Userrepo.save(user);
    }
```

I tried to store the data in the DB, but it's showing GET not supported error.

Answer (score 2):

You used the annotation @PostMapping, which is used to map a request with the method POST, you're trying to access this path with a request using the method GET, try using a request with the method POST instead or switching to the annotation @GetMapping

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/adduser",method=RequestMethod.POST)  i also used this but its showing same error

Comment: @SURYA-DEVELOPER That still expects a POST, while whatever you're using to perform the request to this API uses a GET while it should be using a POST. Given using POST is the correct semantics here, you should fix whatever performs the request to switch to using POST instead of GET.